# windir captured as output of for look is not getting resolved as environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am fetching the InetSrv folder's path from registry and persisting in local variable.
now when trying Change directory command (CD) on that saved variable, then its throwing error.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set vb_path=""
for /f "tokens=1-2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" /v InstallPath') do (set vb_path=%%C)
echo %vb_path%
cd %vb_path%
ENDLOCAL
```

output is

```
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CALL set "vb_path=%%C"`.

This would expand `%windir%` part of `%windir%\system32\inetsrv`

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "vb_path="
for /f "tokens=1-2*" %%A in ('
        REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" /v InstallPath
    ') do (CALL set "vb_path=%%C")
echo %vb_path%
cd %vb_path%
ENDLOCAL
```